# How to slice a string from a single column of a large data set?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a large data set with one column.
Like this

```
zinc finger protein 185 OS=Homosapiens OX=9606 GN=ZNF PE=1 SV=3
podocin OS=Homosapiens OX=9606 GN=NPHS2 PE=1 SV=1
```

I am trying to slice out the characters after GN= using Pandas in Jupyter notebook into a single column.
like

```
ZNF185
NPHS2
```

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO smad. It's really difficult to understand your data. Are you able to reformat it as the column should appear?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show what you have tried? A sample of the dataset would also be helpful.

Comment: Not sure about the `"185"` in the first example, but something along the lines of `df['column_name'].str.extract(r'GN=(.*?)\s')` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that what you wanted but you can get separate dataset by doing the following :

```
a = "OX=9606 GN=ZNF PE=1 SV=3 podocin OS=Homosapiens OX=9606 GN=NPHS2 PE=1 SV=1"
[gn_word for gn_word in a.split() if word.startswith('GN=')]
```